# How can I assign a SoundPool Object to an element created by Gridview in Java?

Tags: java, android, gridview, soundpool

I'm working on an Android App that displays 151 pictures via Gridview. I have 151 sounds and I want to assign every sound to a single image, so I can play that sound tapping on an Image.
I'm using SoundPool. Ideas about how can I do this thing?

```
package com.example.thefe.newsmartkedex;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.thefe.newsmartkedex.R.raw.pkmn1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int pkmn1, pkmn2, pkmn3;
    SoundPool mySoundPool = new SoundPool (1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pkmn1 = mySoundPool.load(this, R.raw.pkmn1, 1);
        pkmn2 = mySoundPool.load(this, R.raw.pkmn2, 1);
        pkmn3 = mySoundPool.load(this, R.raw.pkmn3, 1);


        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                 int position, long id) {
                position += 1; //forget about this
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mySoundPool.play(/*???*/,1,1,1,0,1);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

My ImageAdapter Class works like this:

```
package com.example.thefe.newsmartkedex;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by TheFe on 27/09/2016.
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList list) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.pkmn1, R.drawable.pkmn2,
            R.drawable.pkmn3, R.drawable.pkmn4,
            R.drawable.pkmn5, R.drawable.pkmn6,
            R.drawable.pkmn7, R.drawable.pkmn8,
            R.drawable.pkmn9, R.drawable.pkmn10,
            R.drawable.pkmn11, R.drawable.pkmn12,
            R.drawable.pkmn13, R.drawable.pkmn14,
            R.drawable.pkmn15, R.drawable.pkmn16,
            R.drawable.pkmn17, R.drawable.pkmn18,
            R.drawable.pkmn19, R.drawable.pkmn20,
            R.drawable.pkmn21, R.drawable.pkmn22,
            R.drawable.pkmn23, R.drawable.pkmn24,
            R.drawable.pkmn25, R.drawable.pkmn26,
            R.drawable.pkmn27, R.drawable.pkmn28,
            R.drawable.pkmn29, R.drawable.pkmn30,
            R.drawable.pkmn31, R.drawable.pkmn32,
            R.drawable.pkmn33, R.drawable.pkmn34,
            R.drawable.pkmn35, R.drawable.pkmn36,
            R.drawable.pkmn37, R.drawable.pkmn38,
            R.drawable.pkmn39, R.drawable.pkmn40,
            R.drawable.pkmn41, R.drawable.pkmn42,
            R.drawable.pkmn43, R.drawable.pkmn44,
            R.drawable.pkmn45, R.drawable.pkmn46,
            R.drawable.pkmn47, R.drawable.pkmn48,
            R.drawable.pkmn49, R.drawable.pkmn50,
            R.drawable.pkmn51, R.drawable.pkmn52,
            R.drawable.pkmn53, R.drawable.pkmn54,
            R.drawable.pkmn55, R.drawable.pkmn56,
            R.drawable.pkmn57, R.drawable.pkmn58,
            R.drawable.pkmn59, R.drawable.pkmn60,
            R.drawable.pkmn61, R.drawable.pkmn62,
            R.drawable.pkmn63, R.drawable.pkmn64,
            R.drawable.pkmn65, R.drawable.pkmn66,
            R.drawable.pkmn67, R.drawable.pkmn68,
            R.drawable.pkmn69, R.drawable.pkmn70,
            R.drawable.pkmn71, R.drawable.pkmn72,
            R.drawable.pkmn73, R.drawable.pkmn74,
            R.drawable.pkmn75, R.drawable.pkmn76,
            R.drawable.pkmn77, R.drawable.pkmn78,
            R.drawable.pkmn79, R.drawable.pkmn80,
            R.drawable.pkmn81, R.drawable.pkmn82,
            R.drawable.pkmn83, R.drawable.pkmn84,
            R.drawable.pkmn85, R.drawable.pkmn86,
            R.drawable.pkmn87, R.drawable.pkmn88,
            R.drawable.pkmn89, R.drawable.pkmn90,
            R.drawable.pkmn91, R.drawable.pkmn92,
            R.drawable.pkmn93, R.drawable.pkmn94,
            R.drawable.pkmn95, R.drawable.pkmn96,
            R.drawable.pkmn97, R.drawable.pkmn98,
            R.drawable.pkmn99, R.drawable.pkmn100,
            R.drawable.pkmn101, R.drawable.pkmn102,
            R.drawable.pkmn103, R.drawable.pkmn104,
            R.drawable.pkmn105, R.drawable.pkmn106,
            R.drawable.pkmn107, R.drawable.pkmn108,
            R.drawable.pkmn109, R.drawable.pkmn110,
            R.drawable.pkmn111, R.drawable.pkmn112,
            R.drawable.pkmn113, R.drawable.pkmn114,
            R.drawable.pkmn115, R.drawable.pkmn116,
            R.drawable.pkmn117, R.drawable.pkmn118,
            R.drawable.pkmn119, R.drawable.pkmn120,
            R.drawable.pkmn121, R.drawable.pkmn122,
            R.drawable.pkmn123, R.drawable.pkmn124,
            R.drawable.pkmn125, R.drawable.pkmn126,
            R.drawable.pkmn127, R.drawable.pkmn128,
            R.drawable.pkmn129, R.drawable.pkmn130,
            R.drawable.pkmn131, R.drawable.pkmn132,
            R.drawable.pkmn133, R.drawable.pkmn134,
            R.drawable.pkmn135, R.drawable.pkmn136,
            R.drawable.pkmn137, R.drawable.pkmn138,
            R.drawable.pkmn139, R.drawable.pkmn140,
            R.drawable.pkmn141, R.drawable.pkmn142,
            R.drawable.pkmn143, R.drawable.pkmn144,
            R.drawable.pkmn145, R.drawable.pkmn146,
            R.drawable.pkmn147, R.drawable.pkmn148,
            R.drawable.pkmn149, R.drawable.pkmn150,
            R.drawable.pkmn151
    };
}
```

Comment: Where are your images?

Comment: inside the res/drawable folder, audio is in res/raw

Comment: Do you have a model class?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class that holds a reference to your image and the sound associated with it. When an item is clicked, get the object corresponding to the object, load the `SoundPool` object using the reference and play it.

```
public class Item {

    int imageId;
    int soundID;

    public Item(int imageId, int soundID){
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.soundID = soundID;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public int getSoundID() {
        return soundID;
    }

    public void setSoundID(int soundID) {
        this.soundID = soundID;
    }
}
```

Create a List of Items,

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Items>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    items.add(new Item(R.drawable.your_image_id, R.raw.your_sound_id));
}
```

Pass this list to your adapter. You will to modify the constructor of `ImageAdapter`. Initialize your adapter like this,

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, items);
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Inside you onItemClick,

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // your code

        Item selectedItem = items.get(position);
        int soundID = selectedItem.getSoundID();
        pkmn1 = mySoundPool.load(MainActivity.this, soundID, 1);
        mySoundPool.play(pkmn1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, excellent answer, I'll try it later as soon as I come back home :)

Comment: OK, I'm having some troubles. I'm working on it since last night and I've got some questions (forgive me, I'm still learning): First of all I get an annoying "cannot resolve method getSoundID()" and I really don't know how to fix it. Second I didn't understand what do I have to put where you wrote //getters and setters in class Item.Last, I get an error where I do the load option: it tells men that "this" can't be used because the type is wrong (expected context, given AdapterView.OnClickListener"...may you help me?

Comment: Wow, this is very embarassing, since my app crashes as soon as I tap on an Image (I'm not saying it's your fault, obviously I'm not understanding your precious help)...if you want to keep helping me in some ways I'll be very glad of this, but if you got other things to do I'm not going to be offended. Thanks in any case :)